# Centering a logo in a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

My final goal is to create what you see in image B. Note: the menu bar must be centered on the page.  I did create B by setting the vertical-align on the image to middle. However, as a result of doing this my dropdown menu is slightly separated from the main header. Therefore, i cannot select the sub-menu items when i move my mouse cursor down. Any ideas on making this work ? Thanks Jillian

[image: Example A and B]

```
<style>


      #nav{
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-width:1px 0;
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #nav li{
            position:relative;
            display:inline;
        }
        #nav a{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:10px;
        }
        #nav ul{
            position:absolute;
            /*top:100%; Uncommenting this makes the dropdowns work in IE7 but looks a little worse in all other browsers. Your call. */
            left:-9999px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            text-align:left;
        }
        #nav ul li{
            display:block;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul{
            left:0;
        }
        #nav li:hover a{
            text-decoration:underline;
            background:#f1f1f1;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul a{
            text-decoration:none;
            background:none;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
            background:#f1f1f1;
        }
        #nav ul a{
            white-space:nowrap;
            display:block;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        }
        a{
            color:#c00;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
            background:#f1f1f1;
        }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="link1.html">Item one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item two</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="link1.html">Sub1</a></li>
   <li><a href="link1.html">Sub2</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="double-line">
  <a href="index.php"><img style="vertical-align:middle"  src="img/logo_large.png" alt="logo" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="link4.html">The Fourth</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5.html">Last</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just offset the submenu up to cover the logo height.

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuass/) using the google logo and altering the submenu style by adding this:

```
#nav ul {
   top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do something like,

```
#nav ul{
  background:url('img/logo_large.png') no-repeat center center;
  /* more CSS here */
}
```

unless you have to use it as a link. Then consider `position:absolute;` for the image with `#nav ul` being `position:relative;`, and use a floating layout for the other links with a `z-index` to overlap where they should hang over.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert in CSS `line-height: X px`; (for example, parent div height) in each menu title (Item one, Item two, The Fourth, etc.)